# Накачанный и накаченный

Tags: орфография

"Накачан(н)ый" от слова "качать", а "накаченный" от "качели"? Я права? А как назвать мужчину-культуриста, накачан(н)ый? И сколько "н" верно?

Answer (score 6):

1) ВЫКАЧЕННЫЙ

Выкатить (бочку, пушку, велосипед, всё, что имеет колеса) → выкаченный, глагольный суффикс И соответствует суффиксу ЕНН причастия. (Слово "накаченный" должно образовываться от глагола "накатить", но такую ситуацию трудно придумать.)

2) НАКАЧАННЫЙ

Накачать, закачать воздух (в шины, в резервуар) → накачанный, глагольный суффикс А сохраняется, добавляется суффикс НН причастия. Глаголы "качать и качаться" имеют значение перемещения взад-вперед, движения аналогичного характера совершаются при работе с насосом. Современные культуристы "накачивают" себе мышцы на тренажерах, также совершая периодические движения, и поэтому становятся "накачанными".

3) Выбор НН  в слове "накачанный" можно проверить по наличию приставки. В краткой форме в причастии пишется одна Н: шины накачаны.

Answer (score 2):

Накаченный - тот, которого накатили.(Хотя как-то неблагозвучно)
Накачанный - тот, каторого накачали. В нашем слчае, конечно, накачанный))

Answer (score 1):

НАКАЧАННЫЙ - от качать(ся) - допустим, спортсмен, хотя необязательно (можно МЯЧ и т.п.)
Соответственно НН - во всех случаях, ибо приставка... Можно и без Н вообще: КАЧОК

НАКАЧЕННЫЙ - от накатить: допустим, вина (фиг.)