# Выражение "в полном неглиже"

Tags: фразеология

Употребляется довольно часто, в т.ч. авторами книг. При этом имеется ввиду полная нагота. Это неправильное употребление? Или уже вошло в норму? Что вообще означает "в полном неглиже"?

Comment: Это означает "в крайне небрежном виде" (спросонья, в бигудях и т. п.).

Comment: А вот здесь скорее "обнаженная": https://books.google.com/books?id=YMo7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT602&lpg=PT602&dq=%22%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&source=bl&ots=Nbvkm8dxUY&sig=dUiT_p9fskIL2lsE3POapAAhZS4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY4-emv-nYAhXQFsAKHXWiCasQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=jKo3qavXVFYC&pg=PT14&lpg=PT14&dq=%22%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&source=bl&ots=anmc9jDBLL&sig=-v596l3l7AW2o7AIZpPaDMzpmXE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY4-emv-nYAhXQFsAKHXWiCasQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=d3RRDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT651&lpg=PT651&dq=%22%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&source=bl&ots=FA5h3ah-xB&sig=Knd38lwcqkFJKyyeWt2NA4jOq5Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY4-emv-nYAhXQFsAKHXWiCasQ6AEIRDAF#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=k5NADwAAQBAJ&pg=PT321&lpg=PT321&dq=%22%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&source=bl&ots=LR7QA1piXn&sig=mE4_vJxHCF_waNFQFY06KMMBo4I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY4-emv-nYAhXQFsAKHXWiCasQ6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы ни говорили словари, а выражение "в полном неглиже" означает "нагишом". 
Можете считать это сленгом.

Вот что пишет некто Анатолий Воробей (avva): (https://avva.livejournal.com/56122.html#/56122.html):

Первоначальный смысл "в неглиже" - "в длинном домашнем халате/платье" или "в небрежном, полуодетом виде". В какой-то момент появляется значение "в голом виде, нагишом".

Это пример общего явления - сдвига смысла редкого, "учёного" слова ввиду неправильного его понимания новым поколением читателей (или вообще носителей языка).

Вариант "в полном неглиже" появляется, по-видимому, из-за необходимости различать два значения: "в полном неглиже" недвусмысленно означает только "нагишом"

Comment: В Нацкорпусе нет выражения "в полном неглиже", в словарях, думаю, тоже нет.  Легкий утренний наряд может быть прозрачным - вот вариант полного неглиже. Откуда взялось это выражение?  в любом случае  использовать его  как полное отсутствие одежды можно было изначально только в ироническом смысле - образно, другими словами.  (дословно  в  полном неглиже - это в совершенной небрежности). А дальше - трудно сказать,  слово может развивать свое значение. Пока в каждом случае нужно судите по контексту автора, а не по мнению отдельных лиц, решающих за всех.

Comment: Много лет назад, ни разу не слыша это выражение ( в полном неглиже), я использовал его в смысле " в полном неглЯже", т.е. там не на что глЯдеть, не на что смотреть. Об одежде здесь речь не идёт.

Answer (score -1):

**Неглиже́** (от фр. négligé — «небрежное») — один из видов женской ночной рубашки, обычно выглядящий как длинное платье, сродни халату. По предназначению неглиже — лёгкое и удобное домашнее ночное или утреннее одеяние.

**Если судить по книгам,** то там используется именно это значение: одетый во что-то легкое, домашнее, не для выхода на улицу

На пороге хозяйка **в неглиже** премило прощается с накачанным массажистом. [Ольга Новикова. Каждый убивал // «Сибирские огни», 2012]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2++%ED%E5%E3%EB%E8%E6%E5

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33865/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Накаченный - тот, которого накатили. Но Нацкопрус...

Comment: Удивительно, что этот ответ принят. Он не только не отвечает на вопрос, но даже не делает попытки. Вопрос был "что означает "в полном неглиже", а не про значение слова "неглиже".