# Современное значение слова "накачанный"

Tags: причастия

Непонятно, слово ***"накачанный"*** в данном контексте: "*спортсмены накачаны"* - является прилагательным или причастием?
Правильно ли писать "накачаны" или нужно "накачанны", ведь слово синонимично другим прилагательным - *мускулисты, спортивны*, с наречием "очень" слово употребляется, употребляется форма сравнительной степени - накачанней, однако в орфографическом словаре указан вариант только с одной "н". Может ли быть такое, что данное значение слова еще не зафиксировано, поэтому нет варианта с "нн" в краткой форме?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147902/discussion-on-question-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Я думаю, что вся необходимая информация **уже есть** в орфографическом словаре. Там указано: ***накачанный***; кр. ф. -ан, -ана (от ***накачать***).
2. Слово «накачанный»  есть в толковом словаре Кузнецова: ***Накачанный***, разг. Имеющий развитые мышцы, мускулы. Значение **переносное**, это прилагательное. А краткой формы  с двумя НН в орфографическом словаре нет. Почему? Обычно у парных прилагательных/причастий две формы: *тучи рассеяны ветром;  вы так рассеянны.*
3. Посмотрим в словарях значения глагола ***накачать/накачивать*** (мышцы). Такое значение есть у Ефремовой, но еще нет у Кузнецова. Значение глаголов ***накачать*** и ***накачаться*** уже переносное. В орфографический словарь указано "от накачать" (**в прямом и переносном значении**), а про прилагательные/причастия там ничего не сказано. *Шины **накачаны**, спортсмены **накачаны**,* одна и та же форма для причастий (**прямое** значение) и прилагательных (**переносное** значение).
4. В **практических** текстах также утвердилась форма краткого прилагательного с одной Н: кр. ф. -ан, -ана (от ***накачать мышцы***).
5. **[По правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62)** (см. Примечание к п.7) некоторые отглагольные прилагательные пишутся в полной форме с двумя НН а **в краткой — с одним Н**, подобно причастиям, с которыми их сближает наличие приставки и вид производящего глагола.
6. **Примеры**

Марина Вишневецкая. Вышел месяц из тумана (1997). *Олег — метр с кепкой, но **накачан** он классно.*

Лев Дворецкий. Шакалы (2000). *А я решил, что десантник. У них обычно ребята здорово **накачаны***.

Александра Маринина. Не мешайте палачу (1996). *Если б не это – высокий стройный мальчик, под кожей ни грамма жира, даже мускулы как бы **не накачаны***.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (варианты записи слов в орфографическом словаре РАН)

**Вариант 1.** Краткое причастие (Н) и прилагательное (НН)

***рассеянный***; кр. ф. прич. -ян, -яна; кр. ф. прил. (невнимательный) -ян, -янна

**Вариант 2.** Краткое причастие (Н) и две формы для прилагательного (Н и НН)

***насыщенный;*** кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (с дополн.: жизнь насыщена приключениями) и -ен, -енна (без дополн.: жизнь насыщенна, содержательна).

**Вариант 3.** Краткое прилагательное (Н)

***поношенный***; кр. ф. -ен, -ена;   ***заплаканный***; кр. ф. -ан, -ана

Сравнить: ***накачанный;*** кр. ф. -ан, -ана (от накачать)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147915/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Переносное значение слова — вторичное лексическое значение слова, возникшее в результате переноса прямого значения слова на название другого предмета, признака или действия по какому-либо сходству. Значение не переносное, поскольку нет переноса прямого значения на другой тип понятий.

Comment: @sharon Например, в Орфографическом словаре  русского языка (2008 г.) указывается, когда слово является причастием, а когда прилагательным. В некоторых ситуациях указывается такая формулировка: прич. в знач. прил. Например, я влюблена в него, в то же время есть и редко употребляемое причастие: она влюблена им. Анализируемое слово отмечено в этом словаре, у него помета "прич.", однако это словарь 2008. Думаю, что значение появилось не так давно, поэтому не успели внести корректировку для данного случая, а может, и не стали, поскольку словоупотребление   узконаправленно, хотя, по мне,

Comment: должно быть так: прич. в знач. прил.., поскольку стандартной "страдательности" здесь нет, однако все равно чувствуется глагольность в слове (накачался). Накачанными все же не рождаются, ими становятся.

Comment: @Ajgy Почему нет страдательности? *Мышцы накачан(н)ны, пресс накачан.*

Comment: @oleedd Вы не учитываете контекст. Речь идет о человеке.

Comment: @Ajgy Но словари не учитывают контекст. И нельзя сказать, что в "человек накачан" и "пресс накачан" разные части речи. Смысл ведь тот же. "Человек накачан" можно считать метонимией, так как накачан не весь человек, а его мышцы.

Comment: @oleedd Не надо нести чушь: девочка рассеянна/заклятье рассеяно. Разные контексты - это разные написания. Тут так же, отличаются только части речи, а написание совпадает: парни накачаны/мышцы накачаны.

Comment: @Ajgy Это у вас чушь. Здесь разный смысл (*девочка невнимательна, заклятие снято*), а там тот же!

Comment: Комплименты, комплименты... Вот еще пример: НАЧИТАННЫЙ; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. -ан, -анна (она умна и начитанна)   Сам себя накачал, сам себя начитал...

Answer (score 0):

Накачанный - прилагательное, переносное надутый - накачанные мышцы, выглядящие как будто их надули. Но никто его не надувал, он сам раскачался. А может быть и страдательное причастие прошедшего времени. По примеру выезженная лошадь - лошадь выезжена.

Накачаны - не переносное, краткое страдательное причастие прошедшего времени, отсылка к тому, кто накачал или чем накачали. Наркоманы накачаны наркотиками. Накачанный - выглядящий надутым, накачан - накачан чем-то.
Вообще слова накачанные и накачаны - это современные жаргонизмы. Также не нужно путать слова [накачанный и накаченный](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33865/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

> я как-то накач**ан** оптимизмом и верой в хорошие для меня дни.

> ..шины хорошо накач**ан**ы.

> ..губы накач**ан**ы ботоксом.

> Мышцы их, накач**анн**ые регулярными упражнениями..(тут, правда, выходит, что причастие, но тут такое себе, лучше сделать прилагательное "накачанные от регулярных упражнений", чтобы не качать упражнения в мышцы.)

> Кому-то нравятся накачанные руки...

Спортсмены накачаны - не верно, потому что спортсмены - накачанные. А так спортсмены накачаны допингом получаются.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147935/discussion-on-answer-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.